# XeLaTeX xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid paper size: 0bp, 0bp

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to compile .tex file by XeLaTeX under Windows XP-32bit, WinEdt 8.0, MiKTeX 2.9 environment, however, there is no .pdf file after finishing compilation. 
My document is quite simple.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
  test by XeLaTeX
\end{document}
```

Here is final compilation report.
[image]
The report shows that ''xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid paper size: 0bp, 0bp''. What's the problems? Is it because of Windows XP?

Comment: I cannot understand why `ctex-scheme-chinese.def` etc. are
read for such a simple example. In my case, only `book.cls`
and `bk10.clo` are read.
I suspect that you are compiling some other example which
is rather complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, it's my fault. I recompile the file, but the same ''xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid paper size: 0bp, 0bp'' with no .pdf file generated.  The image is updated now. @AkiraKakuto

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an outdated version of the software or to improper installation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody's concern. This problem is solved by uninstalling MiKTeX and reinstalling MiKTeX. Maybe my MiKTeX version is too old, and it works well now after reinstalling.